# App is not updating for iPad Air 2, still showing error message

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, simulator

I'm new to React Native. I follow This Tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZj6uzNRs5E&t=337s
 to link my app with firebase.

But my app is showing error "Unexpected Token (31:13)"

I Updated my code and save it
still, I'm getting the same error message.
I change my code so many times but the error message was same every time.

Below is the complete app.js code code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase'; 
import {Container, Content, Header, Form, Input, Item, Button, Label } from 'native-base';

export default class App extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = ({
//    firstName='',
  //  lastName='',
    email='',
    password=''
    //confirmPassword='',

  })
}

signUpUser = (/*firstName,lastName,*/email,password/*,confirmPassword*/) => {

  try {

    if(this.state.password.length<6){
      alert("please enter atleast 6 character")
    }

     firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailandPassword(email,password)

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.toString[])
  }
}

  render() {
    return (
             <Container styles={styles.container}>
              <Form>
              <Item floatingLabel>
                  <Label>First Name</Label>
                    <Input
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                    onChangeText={(firstName) => this.setState{(firstName)}}
                    />
              </Item>
              <Item floatingLabel>
                  <Label>Last Name</Label>
                    <Input
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    autoCapitalize='none'
                    onChangeText={(lastName) => this.setState{(lastName)}}
                    />
              </Item>
                <Item floatingLabel>
                    <Label>Email</Label>
                      <Input
                      autoCorrect={false}
                      autoCapitalize='none'
                      onChangeText={(email) => this.setState{(email)}}
                      />
                </Item>
                <Item floatingLabel>
                    <Label>Password</Label>
                      <Input
                      secureTextEntry={true}
                      autoCorrect={false}
                      autoCapitalize='none'
                      onChangeText={(password) => this.setState{(password)}}
                      />
                </Item>
                <Item floatingLabel>
                    <Label>Confirm Password</Label>
                      <Input
                      secureTextEntry={true}
                      autoCorrect={false}
                      autoCapitalize='none'
                      onChangeText={(confirmPassword) => this.setState{(confirmPassword)}}
                      />
                </Item>
                <Button style={{marginTop: 10}}
                full
                rounded
                success
                onPress = {() => this.signUpUser(this.state.email,/* this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName,*/this.state.password/*,this.state.confirmPassword*/)}
                ><Text>Sign Up</Text>
                </Button>

              </Form>
             </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

please help me if anyone know about it.

Comment: `error.toString[]` should probably be `error.toString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been caught in this a few times. When you've made an error in your code, when the metro bundler re-bundles the JavaScript, sometimes it throws and exception an error and it doesn't update your code.

If you look in the Metro Bundler window (the one that opens and bundles your JS on initial build) it may have an error in there. I'm guessing that your error may be:

```
error.toString[]
```

it should be:

`error.toString()`

As a comment underneath suggests, it's better to log the error like

`console.log(error)` or `console.log(error.message)`

Comment: Logs works better if you use `console.log(error)` or `console.log(error.message)`

Comment: @ShivamTrivedi - What is the error? (if it gave you the answer could you mark it/upvote the answer)